# stopping MiNiFi on Windows

Tags: windows, apache-minifi

I need the ability to stop MiNiFi running on a windows machine.  Here:
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.4.0/minifi-quick-start/content/stopping_minifi.html

It tells me to use:

```
bin/minifi.sh stop
```

or

```
sudo service minifi stop
```

Unfortunately, I'm using Windows and those commands won't work, not even with Cygwin.

Any ideas, or is my only option to figure our what process(s) in task manager to kill?

Comment: I don't think there is going to be a better option to stop MiNiFi on a windows machine then to terminate the associated processes in task manager.  Unfortunately, I don't know which processes those are.  Another option is to reboot your PC.

Comment: Not so sure the docs are trustworthy, this wasn't made to run well on a Windows machine.  But it recommends using Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage MiNiFi on a windows machine is to create a wrapper for it to run as a windows service.  The shell commands won't work on a PC so your only option to stop minifi is to reboot your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to reboot your machine, but there is also a workaround.

When you start the nifi in command prompt in Windows then do not close that Window. Whenever you want to close nifi, go to that command prompt and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This works and maybe you can press it two or three times because sometimes it takes time to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed.